# Spring Data JDBC Generating Bad HSQLDB Query with Boot 2.3.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

I have a Spring Boot project that uses Spring Data JDBC. The tests use HSQLDB. My repository tests started failing when I attempted an upgrade to Spring Boot 2.3.0.

Spring Data JDBC appears to now quote table and column names. The version of Spring Data JDBC included with Spring Boot 2.2.7 did not.

The project at https://github.com/mrgrew/boot230bug demonstrates the difference. Spring Boot 2.3.0 generates `INSERT INTO "stats.counter" ("COUNTER_NAME") VALUES (?)` which fails. Spring Boot 2.2.7 generates `INSERT INTO stats.counter (counter_name) VALUES (?)` which succeeds.

I'm guessing Spring Data JDBC isn't properly identifying the dialect. My test properties specify `spring.datasource.platform=hsqldb` which I thought would avoid ambiguity.

This *seems* like a bug with the version of Spring Data JDBC included with Spring Boot 2.3.0. Can anyone confirm this is a bug or suggest changes to my demo project that work with Boot 2.3.0?

Thanks in advance for any advice or discussion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I was too quick to ask... A migration guide was published the same day I asked this question! https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/20/migrating-to-spring-data-jdbc-2-0

The migration guide explains what I was observing:

> ### Quoting of Identifiers
>
> Spring Data JDBC 1.x uses table and column names mostly without changing them. This causes problems when you use an SQL key word as a property or entity name or when you tried to use some special character in a column name.
>
> For this reason Spring Data JDBC 2.0 quotes all identifiers by default. This makes the names case-sensitive, at least for most databases. Since we also, by default, convert the names generated into the default letter casing used by the database, this should not cause any problems, assuming you used no quotes in the CREATE TABLE statements, as most people do.

Removing the @Table annotation and schemaName from the Liquibase change log removed my unintended use of quoting and solved the issue. As a bonus, I didn't need to create a schema anymore so I could remove `spring.datasource.platform=hsqldb` and the schema-hsqldb.sql file. See the [fixed](https://github.com/mrgrew/boot230bug/tree/fixed) branch for the working version.

Thanks for the nudge [Jens Schauder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66686/jens-schauder)!

Comment: Great to see that the migration guide helped. Could you add the part that solved your problem in your answer directly, please. Currently this is a "link only" answer which is frowned upon in the SO community, because the link might die which would make the answer useless.